# egrep \b not recognising single quote

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to list all 3 letter words in a file using egrep.

Sample input;

tap

belt

sword

cliff

can't

can

not

---

Regex;

`egrep "\b[a-zA-Z]{3}\b"`

I get my 3 letter words listed, but why is **can't** showing in the results?

EDIT

I have received the answer to my original question and I now use;

`egrep '^[a-zA-Z]{3}$'`

This works because I have only 1 word per line. My question is now updated because that answer is a little brittle.

How would I search for 3 letters words if the input was not 1 word per line but instead in lines and paragraphs?

Comment: probably because `'` counts as a word boundary, and in linguistic terms, that's `can not` which is TWO three-letter words.

Comment: Yes it has can and not listed separately but I don't want can't! Unless I use ^ and $ instead of \b?

Comment: Can you post sample input and expected output?

Comment: if each word is alone on the line, then you don't need word boundaries. `/^...$/` would do the trick.

Comment: `\b` matches anywhere that a word character is next to a non-word character. `n` is a word character `'` is a non-word character, so it matches between them.

Comment: Can you post your transcript as plain text instead of an image? It's very hard to read because the colors don't have much contrast with the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are multiple words per line then you cannot use anchors.

If your grep supports `-P` (PCRE) option then you can use lookahead regex:

```
grep -oiP '\b[a-z]{3}(?=\s|$)' file
```

If `-P` isn't available then you can use:

```
grep -oiE '\b[a-z]{3}(\s|$)' file
```

2nd `grep` will have a trailing space. If you want to remove that as well then use:

```
grep -oiE '\b[a-z]{3}(\s|$)' file | awk '{print $1}'
```

---

**Alternatively** here is an `awk` solution to print all 3 letter fields:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (length($i)==3) print $i}' file
```

If you have `gnu awk` then you can make it even shorter:

```
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]' 'length($0) == 3' file
```

Comment: The `awk` answer is the one I want! It is a general solution I can use anywhere! Thanks

Comment: you can use the `-w` option to match only words... `grep -woiE '[a-z]{3}'` or even `grep -woi '[a-z][a-z][a-z]'`

Comment: @Sundeep: `-w` will also find `can` in `can't` that OP doesn't want.

Comment: right you are, missed that point... `awk` solution seems best as names like `F'nor` will also be taken care...

Answer (score 2):

Since your file appareently has one word per line, anchor to line endings instead of word boundaries.

```
egrep -i '^[a-z]{3}$' | sort
```

The problem with your code is that `\b` matches between any word character and non-word character, and `'` is a non-word character.

Comment: The sample output is consistent with that assumption. He's not using `-o`, but everything is just one word per line.

Comment: or use `-x` option which matches whole line only